# Calendar data binding selects wrong date

Tags: c#, wpf, date, mvvm, calendar

I am using a regular WPF Calendar (System.Windows.Controls.Calendar) in an MVVM application. The calendar shows a month at a time, and the user will pick a single day. The calendar shows a few days of the next month at the bottom, which is fine.

**The problem is** that if I pick a date from the next month (eg the 2nd of the next month) then Calendar first updates the data binding with this date, and then immediately updates it again with the 1st of the month!

This happens for all dates in the next month that I select.

The calendar's SelectedDate and DisplayDate properties are data bound to the view model's Date property.

```xml
<Calendar SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" DisplayDate="{Binding Date}" />
```

The view model looks like this

```c#
public class CalendarProblemDemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _date;

    public CalendarProblemDemoViewModel() 
    {
        _date = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            Debug.Write($"new date {_date}\n");
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }
    // Note: other code omitted, see the github project
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: So you bound both to the same property `Date`. Did you try and see if `SelectedDate` is different than `DisplayDate`?

Comment: That actually solves the problem LOL!  So it has to do with the inner workings of Calendar? I think I'll fire up the disassembler and have a look.

Comment: Glad we were able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind both `SelectedDate` and `DisplayDate` to the same property `Date`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I don't understand why that is really?

Comment: It `Displays` a current Date (not the Gray) but you might `Select` different date (the Gray). So by binding both to the same property, the property will always take the Displayed even if Selected is different.

Comment: You can keep both if you do this: `DisplayDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Good answer! Thank you very much for elaborating!

Comment: No problem. Anytime :)

Comment: On second though, should not the bindings be simplified like this? : `SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"  DisplayDate="{Binding Date, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. I have tried it.